# Simple question: lftp not writing to $LOG --- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: bash, shell, ftp, lftp

I use a  script for work that invokes `lftp` to mirror a directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='ftp.example.com"
USER='pretenduser'
PASS='pretendpass'
TARGETFOLDER='/home/pretenduser/Dropbox/lftp'
SOURCEFOLDER='/files/Inbox'
LOG='/home/pretenduser/Scripts/lftp.log'
lftp -c "
set ftp:ssl-allow no
open $HOST
user $USER $PASS
mirror --verbose --delete $SOURCEFOLDER $TARGETFOLDER
bye
"
>> $LOG
```

`lftp` is not writing to `$LOG`, it creates the file but it's empty.  I have also tried `2>` and `1>` instead of `>>`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put `>>"$LOG"` on the same line as the command, not on the line that gets executed after the `lftp` command has finished.

Comment: @Giles is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Gilles commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349045/simple-question-lftp-not-writing-to-log-what-am-i-doing-wrong#comment617931_349045), your redirection is on a separate line, which means it's a separate (empty) command. The `lftp` command ended with the ending double-quote.

Simply change the `lftp` command to:

```
lftp -c "
set ftp:ssl-allow no
open $HOST
user $USER $PASS
mirror --verbose --delete $SOURCEFOLDER $TARGETFOLDER
bye
" >> $LOG
```